# apache ignores location directive

Tags: apache-2.2

I've uncommented the default section:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 
</Location>
```

then restarted apache ('Syntax OK')

When I run `links http://127.0.0.1/server-status` I see 404 eror page.

```
# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          site.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server site.com (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/www.site.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost site.com (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/www.site.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.site.com
Syntax OK
```

Also I tried to insert the `'Location'` block into `<VirtualHost>` and use the domain name instead of `127.0.0.1` but no luck.

I checked I'm at the proper config file by entering incorrect directive intentionally, that's the correct file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are not hitting it (using links) from source 127.0.0.1 like you think you are. As a test try removing 'Deny from all' and changing to 'Allow from all'.

Comment: ChrisV How can I check it?

Comment: Where's that location block reside?  Do you get a 403 response when you access `/server-status` from a different system?

Comment: @ShaneMadden in both main /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and inside  virtualhost in /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/www.site.com.conf. Yes, I have 403 from another system.

Comment: @Putnik Hmm, is `mod_status` enabled and set to load?  Can't tell if you're on EL or Debian from those paths, different process on each

Comment: (Edited my previous comment) Apache log should show source IP address of your request for /server-status

Comment: @ShaneMadden `apachectl  -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep status` shows `status_module (shared)`. It's RHE 6.5
@ChrisV have just tried to remove 'deny', the same. also, `tail -f  /var/log/httpd/sitename-access.log | grep my-ip` shows `my-ip  - - [20/Nov/2014:06:23:05 -0800] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 404`

Comment: Did you anonomize your source IP address with `my-ip` in your comment? If it was something other than 127.0.0.1 then the `Allow from 127.0.0.1` statement is blocking your request (actually the `Deny from all` is blocking but you need to modify the `Allow from` statement) and so you will need to modify that statement to include source IP addresses from which you want to be able to make requests to the `/server-status` page.

Comment: @ChrisV yes, this is my external IP but as was said, I removed 'deny' block completely, so now it looks `<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
</Location>` Also, I saw 403 usint external IP when the restriction was enabled, now I see 404

Comment: What is result if you set the `Location` directive back to original but change `Allow from 127.0.0.1` to `Allow from my-ip`?

Comment: @ChrisV Have just tested. without my-ip i see 403 as expected, with it I see 404. Perhaps it is related to virtualhosts somehow? I've just done these changes in `location` inside the virtualhost...

Comment: @ChrisV have just disabled at all in vhost, but tested in the main config. The same behavior.

Comment: Hmmm, there must be some other configuration (or application) getting in the way; Perhaps re-writes or a proxy? I would suggest checking for `RewriteRule` in your config files and any .htaccess files.

Comment: @user87664 it was the correct guess. Feel free to convert it to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it looks like the cause was similar: my application had an .htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This took precedence over the Location section. It's rewriting all URLs that don't point to an actual file, and this includes server-status. By adding another RewriteCond before the RewriteRule, I was able to fix it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
```

Another approach is to add an Alias that maps your server-status URL to a different directory, one that doesn't use the .htaccess file. It seems like this can even be a directory that doesn't exist:

```
Alias /server-status /tmp/dummy
```

When updating from httpd 2.2 to 2.4, I also had to grant access to this dummy directory:

```
<Directory /tmp/dummy>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```